# Custom Search Command Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm attempting to make a Custom Search command using the Custom Search API.

Naturally I have no idea how to implement it.  I'm hoping someone can take a look at what I have and help me figure out how to make it work in this style?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils
import time
import os
import dotenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
SEARCH = os.getenv("CUSTOM_SEARCH_API_KEY")

class Util(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @commands.command(name="Search", aliases=["search"])
    @commands.has_permissions(embed_links=True, add_reactions=True)
    async def _search(self, ctx, *, message):
        if not ctx.author.Bot:
            guild = ctx.guild
            msg = ctx.message
            cli = self.client.user
            gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
            embed = discord.Embed(color=gold, name=f"{image.name}", description=f"{image.desc}", timestamp=msg.created_at)
            embed.set_image(url=f"{image.url}")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=cli.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=guild.name, icon_url=guild.icon_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Util(client))
```

I'm using dotenv to store my API key

Basically, I'm wanting it to be a somewhat detailed command.

If searching for posts it will find the exact post. and if searching for images it will go by tag and find a random image matching the selected tag(s).

I would like for it to respond via rich embed if possible.

I'm fully aware my above code won't work at all. I simply put it there as a base for part of the embed that I want to try to implement.

Some help would be much appreciated.

I'm using discord.py rewrite and I have my commands set up through cogs.

This is my `bot.py` file that contains the handler for my cogs.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json
import dotenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
PREFIX = os.getenv("COMMAND_PREFIX")


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)
client.remove_command('help')

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: What is the Custom Search API? What exactly are you searching?

Comment: 1. `if not ctx.message.author.bot`, `bot` has to be in lower case;   

2. sorry but we don't get what you mean. as @PatrickHaugh has said, what is Custom Search API?   

3. `image` is not defined, unless that is part of the code you've got.   

4. `bot = commands.Bot( case_insensitive=True)`

Comment: Custom Search API is a Google Search API that lets you run custom searches. So basicllay when used in a command it allows a more flexible structure such as using tags for some things or just straight up urls if need be.

according to the docs it is often used by websites for building search engines but I've noticed a few people using it for bot commands. Sadly none are right for mine ...

https://developers.google.com/custom-search

Comment: When searching for an image i want the embed to contain the image field, and when searching for a post i want it to use a message field with a list of mark down links to first 5 posts matching the specified criteria. The embed above was a basic idea of what I'm using for embeds and the image part was more a reference to what i want to show there.

I'm trying to figure out how to actually implement everything.

Comment: Also  on an unrelated topic, thank you for the case sensitivity part `ctx.author.bot` part. I was tired asf last night and didn't even notice i had messed up my `ctx.author.bot` section. And I've been trying to figure out how to use that `case_insensitive` flag for some time no with no luck xD

I was literally going through my code searching for typos when i looked here and found the answer to why my commands suddenly took a dump. I didn't even see that typo xD